# datashader import fails - DLL load failed

Tags: python, dll, python-imaging-library, datashader

Getting datashader module installed and imported in jupyter notebook seems tricky somehow. I installed datashader from my anaconda prompt as such:

```
conda install -c bokeh datashader
```

it installed the module correctly in the dir: C:\Users\my_name\Lib\site-packages

(Note that I previsouly installed bokeh version '0.12.11' which is correctly running)

When i run

```
import datashader as ds
```

in jupyter notebook, I get an error. It seems to having trouble importing _imaging from PIL\Image.py but isn't that supposed to be all taken care off in the install ? 
I have PIL module installed by the way. Version '4.2.1' so it is present also in the folder

C:\Users\my_name\Lib\site-packages\PIL

Complete error message:

```
--------------------------------------------------------------------------- ImportError                               Traceback (most recent call last) <ipython-input-1-236dc39df287> in <module>()
----> 1 import datashader as ds

C:\Users\my_name\lib\site-packages\datashader\__init__.py in <module>()
      7                          mean, std, var, count_cat, summary)
      8 from .glyphs import Point                                # noqa (API import)
----> 9 from .pipeline import Pipeline                           # noqa (API import)
     10 from . import transfer_functions as tf                   # noqa (API import)
     11 

C:\Users\my_name\lib\site-packages\datashader\pipeline.py in <module>()
      3 from toolz import identity
      4 
----> 5 from . import transfer_functions as tf
      6 from . import reductions
      7 from . import core

C:\Users\my_name\lib\site-packages\datashader\transfer_functions.py in <module>()
      8 import toolz as tz
      9 import xarray as xr
---> 10 from PIL.Image import fromarray
     11 
     12 

C:\Users\my_name\lib\site-packages\PIL\Image.py in <module>()
     54     # Also note that Image.core is not a publicly documented interface,
     55     # and should be considered private and subject to change.
---> 56     from . import _imaging as core
     57     if PILLOW_VERSION != getattr(core, 'PILLOW_VERSION', None):
     58         raise ImportError("The _imaging extension was built for another "

ImportError: DLL load failed: Kan opgegeven module niet vinden.
```

Comment: Can you try running PIL alone, e.g.:

    python -c "import PIL ; print(PIL.__version__,PIL.__file__)"

Comment: @JamesA.Bednar yes. print(PIL.__version__,PIL.__file__) gives: 4.2.1 C:\Users\my_name\lib\site-packages\PIL\__init__.py

Comment: Can probably be fixed by pinning pillow=4.0.0 ; see https://github.com/bokeh/datashader/issues/534 .